# Android (native): why my socket isn't available to other processes?

Tags: android, security, sockets, android-ndk, ipc

So I'm starting a custom native daemon via init.rc.
It attempts to do either this:

```
x_con = android_get_control_socket("test");
int ret = listen(x_con, 1);
int new_s = accept(x_con, (struct sockaddr*)&peeraddr, &socklen);
```

Or this:

```
x_con = socket_local_server("test:, ANDROID_SOCKET_NAMESPACE_RESERVED, SOCK_STREAM );
int new_s = accept(x_con, (struct sockaddr*)&peeraddr, &socklen);
```

On either occasion, I can see socket under `/dev/socket`, it has access mask of 0666 (due to params set in `init.rc`) but still can't accept any connection (seemingly being unavailable to other processes).

Is it due to 'Paranoid Network' Android's feature?

Answer (score 1):

Android socket model seems to be very strange compared to "normal" sockets.

First, socket has to be initialized via init.rc, given certain permissions.

Next, server application opens it with:

```
x_con = android_get_control_socket("test");
```

Next, listen() and fnctl() calls are required:

```
listen(x_con, 1);
fcntl(x_con, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

After that, a LocalSocket connection from Java can access socket, and socket can accept clients.

Setting non-blocking mode later is allowed too:

```
fnctl(x_con, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Other combinations are unnecessary (and there are some guides like *Working with the Radio Layer Interface (RIL) in Android* - will not link to that low-grade manual - are stating that both socket_local_server and android_get_control_socket are required, which is clearly untrue).

Comment: Some of my experiments are still unclear with access rights - sockets are created with wrong permissions sometimes.